# raw_input() equivalent in cocos2d for Python

Tags: python, input, cocos2d-iphone

I'm building a simple game in cocos2d-0.6.0, and can't figure out how to let the player enter text for a username or other preferences.

I've found only a few examples, like the one [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.cocos2d.user/171), but it isn't quite what I'm looking for. My attempt is below; I used the handling_events.py to try update_text, but it just strings together a list of letters separated by commas.

The ultimate goal is to be able to use a label to pose a question ("What is your name?") and then have the user type a response that will get stored as a variable I can access later (to display on following scenes on a high-score list, for example). Let me know if I can clarify my question.

```
class Settings(cocos.layer.ColorLayer):
is_event_handler = True
def __init__(self):
    super(Settings, self).__init__(0,0,0,255)

    label = cocos.text.Label('Pick a name:',
        font_name='Courier',
        font_size=32,
        anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')
    label.position = 320,650
    self.add(label )

    self.text = cocos.text.Label("", x=100, y=280)
    self.keys_pressed = set()
    self.update_text()
    self.add(self.text)
```

Here is the problem. I don't want to just collect a list of letters and symbols like A,G,T,SEMICOLON.

```
def update_text(self):
    key_names = [pyglet.window.key.symbol_string(k) for k in self.keys_pressed]
    text = 'Keys: ' + ','.join(key_names)
    # Update self.text
    self.text.element.text = text
```

This is optional; it transitions the settings page onto the main gameplay page.

```
def on_key_press(self, k, m):
    if k == key.ENTER:
        director.replace(FadeTransition(
            main_scene, 1))
    else:
        self.keys_pressed.add(k)
        self.update_text()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cocos.director.director.init(height = 690, width = 640)
    settings_scene = cocos.scene.Scene(settings)
    cocos.director.director.run(settings_scene)
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you were looking for something like this. The only downside is that it's all caps right now:

```
import cocos
import pyglet

class Settings(cocos.layer.ColorLayer):
    is_event_handler = True
    def __init__(self):
        super(Settings, self).__init__(0,0,0,255)

        label = cocos.text.Label('Pick a name:',
            font_name='Courier',
            font_size=32,
            anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')
        label.position = 320,650
        self.add( label )

        self.text = cocos.text.Label("", x=100, y=280)
        self.keys_pressed = ""
        self.update_text()
        self.add(self.text)

    def update_text(self):
        # Update self.text
        self.text.element.text = self.keys_pressed

    def on_key_press(self, k, m):
        if k == pyglet.window.key.ENTER:
            print "You Entered: {}".format(self.keys_pressed)
            # cocos.director.director.replace(FadeTransition(main_scene, 1))  # disabled for testing
            cocos.director.director.scene.end()  # added for testing
        else:
            kk = pyglet.window.key.symbol_string(k)
            if kk == "SPACE":
                kk = " "
            if kk == "BACKSPACE":
                self.keys_pressed = self.keys_pressed[:-1]
            else:
                # ignored_keys can obviously be expanded
                ignored_keys = ("LSHIFT", "RSHIFT", "LCTRL", "RCTRL", "LCOMMAND", 
                                "RCOMMAND", "LOPTION", "ROPTION")
                if kk not in ignored_keys:
                    self.keys_pressed = self.keys_pressed + kk
            self.update_text()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cocos.director.director.init(height = 690, width = 640)
    settings_scene = cocos.scene.Scene(Settings())
    cocos.director.director.run(settings_scene)
```